# Does google consider pdf or doc pages and html pages as a duplicate issue?

Tags: html, pdf, seo, duplicates, doc

Do Pdfs or Docs create a duplicate content when they are compared with the simalar or identical content on your webpages?

I have a language learning website which offers classroom resource materials for teachers. I also want to put an interactive exercise of the same material ( as a demo to see the quality of the exercises) on the same page. As a consequence I'll have a print-out version and the interactive version of the same material on the same page.

Is it a real duplicate issue? Are download resources considered as a separate page or the fact that they are on the same page eliminates this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice / asking about search engine behaviour. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are considered as duplicate.

But you can prevent your `pdf` and `docs` from being `indexed`.  You can use robots.txt or x-robots-tag to prevent the PDF files from getting indexed and that way you can solve your problem.

Read more about it here: [html and pdf with same content.](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021584.html)